# Validating alphabets only stored in a string in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flexbuilder

I am trying to validate if only alphabets are typed in a text box. The code i am using is

```
<mx:StringValidator id="loginValidator"     source="{loginTextField}" property="text" required="true" minLength="2" />


validatorErrorArray = Validator.validateAll([loginValidator, ...])
```

Now the problem is, it also validates characters like */- and ;',./ etc i want to validate only numbers and or alphabets. If anyone can point out mistake and changes that should be made

Best Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want Only Alphabets and numbers to accepted you can use restrict property.

```
<s:TextInput restrict="0-9a-zA-Z"/>
```

This will allow only numbers and alphabets.